# Compute the exit time of $M_t = W_t^2 - t$ from $[-R, R]$

Tags: probability, martingales

I have a question in my textbook that states:
Apply the optional stopping theorem for the martingale $ M_t = W_t^2 -t $ to show that $E[\tau] = R^2$.

This exercise came right after the section on dynkin's formula so i suppose I need to apply it. However, my main difficulty comes from not being able to find the generator of the stated process as it is:
$$
dM_t = W_t dW_t
$$
which is not in form of 
$$
dX_t = b(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dW_t
$$
and the latter form is needed to compute the generator. Without the generator I can't apply dynkin's and I am rather lost on what to do. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add the precise definition of $\tau$ to your question?

Comment: i apologize $\tau$ is the stopping time, earliest time when $M_t$ exits the region $[-R, R]$

Comment: So you are sure that $\tau$ is the exit time of $M$ and not the exit time of $W$, yes? Because the latter case (i.e. $\tau$ being the exit time of $W$) would be somewhat more reasoable, from my point of view.

Comment: Yea i know right. The generator of W is found easily and dynkin's can be applied. I am not sure how to find the generator of M.

Comment: There is no generator of $M$. In order to associate a generator with a process, you need to know that the process is Markovian... this approach won't work here.

Comment: @saz ok thanks for the input. Since dynkin's formula won't work in this case maybe I will try something else.

Comment: I suspect it's simply a typo. In which book did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Introduction to stochastic calculus by ovidu calin. He posted it on his edu website.  Chapter 8 exercise 8.5.2. edited to add link. link: https://people.emich.edu/ocalin/Teaching_files/D18N.pdf

Comment: Ok nvm I misread the question. I am supposed to use the martingale to find out the exit time of a BROWNIAN MOTION from the region $[-R,R]$. And apparently this is a really classic question too. Thanks for the help saz. At least i found out the generator of the martingale doesn't exists.